# I am facing Error(Cannot find working tool) in rarfile extraction in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract a rarfile using python rarfile lib.
this is my code

```
 import rarfile as rar
    def Extractor(extract_to_folder, file, base_file_path):  
        rar_ = rar.RarFile(base_file_path)
        rar_.extract(rar_, extract_to_folder)
        rar_.close()

Extractor('F:\MyFiles\myExFolder', 'howToAccess.txt', 'F:\MyFiles\River.rar')
```

after executing the script, the following error is raised:

> raise RarCannotExec("Cannot find working tool")
> rarfile.RarCannotExec: Cannot find working tool

Comment: Do you actually have a tool on your host that supports RAR extraction? You might need to install it first, as described there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251033/not-managing-to-extract-rar-archive-using-rarfile-module

Answer (score 5):

If you have WinRar installed in your machine.
configure the path of winrar in the system environment variable , and then restart your editor.

Hope, problem will be fixed.

[image]

Comment: this worked for me on Windows 11, after adding WinRar to the PATH and re-starting PyCharm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So most likely you are missing the tool that extracts files out of your RAR file.  Assuming you are using Ubuntu, run one of the following commands to solve your issue:

```
sudo apt install bsdtar
```

or

```
sudo apt install unrar
```

Answer (score 0):

worked on windows 7, only do same above: add variable environment , and
RESTART ,[image]