# Rar File issue with Extract

Tags: python, python-3.6, rar

raise RarCannotExec("Cannot find working tool")

```
import rarfile

rarpath = '/home/server/test_rar/ABC.rar'

def unrar(file):
   rf=rarfile.RarFile(file)
   rf.extractall()

unrar(rarpath)
```

Comment: And that's why https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/faq.html#id2 exists. Always check the docs =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have already read this and take an example (https://pypi.org/project/unrar/) from here but when I try it is give me an error about the "cannot find working tool"

Comment: If you've read it, then you've read that this package does not unrar archives itself, but needs to have `unrar` installed on the system so that it can tell the unrar tool to do the actual unpacking. So: do you have `unrar` installed, with its location added to the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: (And on a sidenote, you probably want to update Python to 3.7, as 3.6 [is no longer supported](https://devguide.python.org/versions/). Not a huge difference, but at this point we're on 3.11 and you almost certainly want to be on at least 3.10 for all the speed gains)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have installed unrar and rarfile and with latest version

Comment: And when you run `unrar` on the CLI, does that work? (and also: these are important details that [should be in your post](/help/how-to-ask) so please [edit] them in. Note as "edit ...." but just update your post to be a complete description of your setup, how you got to that setup, and what happens when you run things)

Answer (score 0):

WinRAR is proprietary software. You also need to have it.
An actual answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357670/i-am-facing-errorcannot-find-working-tool-in-rarfile-extraction-in-python)

Comment: No one said this was on windows (yet), and winrar is not required in the slightest for `rarfile` to do its job. If details are missing, remember to ask folks to add those details to their post.

Comment: I check the example you mention but it is not working on python3.6 unrar and rarfile both install with the latest version